# Get DataTable from DataGridView respecting filters and sorting

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView` filled with data. I'm using some code like this:

```
System.Data.DataTable dataTable1;
System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource bindingSource1;
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;

// (...)

bindingSource1.DataSource = dataTable1;

dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

bindingSource1.Filter = "Some Filter Here";
```

What I need now is to recover the data that are in `dataGridView1`. But it don't need to be complicated. my dataGridView1 is readonly so the only thing I need is respect the order and the filter used, and export the data to a `DataTable`.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: The data in `dataGridView1` is exactly your `bindingSource1`, what do you want more?

Comment: I need export the data in `bindingSource1` to a new `DataTable`. I'm try get `bindingSource1.DataSource` but here I have all data, I need the filtered data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need the filtered rows displaying in `DataGridView` as DataTable.
You can make use of [DataTable.DefaultView property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.defaultview.aspx) for this purpose which includes all the filters.

Try this

```
BindingSource bs = (BindingSource)dataGridView1.DataSource;
DataTable table = (DataTable)bs.DataSource;
DataTable filtered = table.DefaultView.ToTable();// here we get filtered datatable
```