# How can I save filtered DataGridView data into Excel using EPPlus?

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview, epplus

How can I import filtered data from the `DataGridView` into Excel using EPPlus?
I don't know where to start, I haven't found anything similar to my problem.

This is the code for my save button:

```
SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM statusrouted.routed", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
            {
                using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);


                    ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(DateTime.Today.ToString("MMMM-yyyy"));

                    ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromDataTable( dt, true);


                    saveFileDialog1.Title = "Save as Excel";
                    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "";
                    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files(2007)|*.xlsx";

                    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            pck.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"" + saveFileDialog1.FileName));
                            recentsToolStripMenuItem1.AddRecentItem(@"" + saveFileDialog1.FileName);
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            DialogResult reminder = MessageBox.Show("Cannot save file, file opened in another program.\nClose it first! ", "Save Failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for my filter in a `textbox_textchanged` event:
I don't know if this is important.

```
DataView DV = new DataView(dt);
string oks;
if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
{
    oks = "ffrom";
}
else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 1)
{
    oks = "office";
}
else if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 2)
{
    oks = "code";
}

else
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 3)
    {
        oks = "datein";
    }
    else
    {
        oks = "dateout";
    }
}

DV.RowFilter = string.Format( oks+ " LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox5.Text);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = DV;
dataGridView1.ClearSelection();
```

Comment: found this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126940/get-datatable-from-datagridview-respecting-filters-and-sorting) tried transforming it to fit my code, didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! I just changed this:

```
ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
```

to this:

```
ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromDataTable((this.maindgv.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.ToTable(), true);
```

I'm not really sure how it worked but I think it's because `dt` is the data being loaded onto the `DataGridView` while `(this.maindgv.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.ToTable()` is the data currently shown on the `DataGridView`. I'm not sure though.

Comment: Your assumptions about the data are correct. That was the main point of my answer, that passing the `DataTable` exports all data to Excel while passing `DataView.ToTable()` exports all post-filtered data. Sorry if that was lost in all the extra details about using `ClosedXML` instead of `ExcelPackage`.